# Limit number of JSON results

Tags: javascript, jquery, json, youtube

I'm trying to display the top 5 videos of a channel. However I'm struggling to limit it to just the five.

```
var playListURL = 'http://gdata.youtube.com/feeds/api/users/example/uploads?v=2&alt=json&callback=?';
var videoURL= 'http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=';
$.getJSON(playListURL, function(data) {
var list_data="";

    $.each(data.feed.entry, function(i, item) {
            var feedTitle = item.title.$t;
            var feedURL = item.link[1].href;
            var fragments = feedURL.split("/");
            var videoID = fragments[fragments.length - 2];
            var url = videoURL + videoID;
            var thumb = "http://img.youtube.com/vi/"+ videoID +"/default.jpg";
            list_data += '<a href="'+ url +'" title="'+ feedTitle +'"><div class="thumbcrop" style="background-image:url('+thumb+');background-size:cover; background-position:center;"></div></a>';
    });
$(list_data).appendTo(".videoClass");
});
```

How can I achieve this? I have tried (unsuccessfully)  clauses such as `while(i<6)` and `if(i<6)` but neither of them display any results at all.

Comment: Is there a reason why you are not using `max-results` as a parameter in your `playListURL`? Is there something I am not catching?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If you don't want to get all the results, don't use each, which *does* iterate through all the results in the first place. Simple as that. For limited and known number of steps use simple logic as:

```
for (var i = 0; i <= 4; i++) {
    var item = data.feed.entry[i];
    // your other stuff goes here
}
```

...or, as other state correctly, ommit your query by 5 in the first place and then use `each` freely.

Comment: Thanks! I didn't realise that `each` fetches every single result. Will try this out!

Answer (score 4):

In the url that you are requesting your results you can add an extra parameters `&max-results=5` so you can restrict the number of your feeds.

so you will have

```
var playListURL = 'http://.../uploads?v=2&alt=json&max-results=5&callback=?';
```

More on youtube data api [parameters](https://developers.google.com/youtube/2.0/developers_guide_protocol_api_query_parameters#max-resultssp)